# Drupal 7: Where is the footer text

Tags: drupal-7

New to drupal 7, just started on a client app.  There is footer text appearing on each page.  No a big deal, right, should be in one of the blocks the previous developer set up?  Nope. No block contains this info/text.

This text has to be embedded directly into one of the drupal php page.  Where should I look in the files?  Tried to do a search in the files, but no luck with the IDE I have.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For others wondering - look in the sites/all/themes/"your theme"/page.tp.php file.  Some programmers may put stuff here .

Answer (score 0):

If thats not in the block,

1. You can check in the all the `tpl` files under your `your_theme/templates/` folder.
2. If the page is `views` page, try looking on the `footer` section in the views itself.